# How to access value in SFSafariViewController that was previously set in the Safari App

Tags: swift, swift2, sfsafariviewcontroller

Steps:

1. User Clicks on Universal Link, opens in safari, if they don't have the app then a cookie is set and the app store opens.
2. User opens newly downloaded app, upon initial launch, SFSafariViewController is opened with a different URL that checks for that initially set value / cookie and then calls URL Scheme with the value.

The problem I'm having is that the SFSafariViewControlelr can't get the value set in the initial Safari App. What are some alternative solutions to achieve this goal? I'm very new to Universal Links / URL Schemes and not sure how to achieve this goal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.
You may be having problems with the fact that `SFSafariViewController`'s are sandboxed.

I would maybe have a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/mackuba/SafariAutoLoginTest) which pretty cleanly demonstrates the principle.

It's important to setup a redirect from your webservice if you want to use the cookie data outside of the `SFSafariViewController` itself.

Hope this helps,

Liam